# Learning KeyEvents

Tags: java, swing

I am relatively new to java and was trying to learn how to make a program where there is this circle and I can move it around using the arrow keys. After shifting through a bunch of examples I was able to put something together. Although I am unsure how to create a KeyEvent. Any help with what I am missing would be awesome.

This is what I have so far.

```
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel 
{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    private void moveBallUP() {
        x = x + 0;
        y = y + 1;       
    }

    private void moveBallDOWN() {
        x = x + 0;
        y = y - 1;       
    }

    private void moveBallLEFT() {
        x = x + 1;
        y = y + 0;       
    }

    private void moveBallRIGHT() {
        x = x - 1;
        y = y + 0;       
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);     
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fillOval(y, x, 50, 50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample Frame");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) 
        {
            game.moveBallUP();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) 
        {
            game.moveBallDOWN();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            game.moveBallLEFT();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
        {
            game.moveBallRIGHT();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am relatively new to java"* - Welcome, use the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to register for notificaiton for particular key events

Comment: As a general recommendation, you should override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`. You're also operating in an "event driven" environment, which is using an observer pattern to provide notifications when things occur.  When using Swing, you should also avoid using `Thead.sleep`, as you could prevent the UI from been updated or been able to respond to new events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several steps to solving this: first, use a `KeyListener`. Add the following code to the `Game` class; this will represent which buttons are pressed:

```
private boolean upPressed=false;
private boolean downPressed=false;
private boolean leftPressed=false;
private boolean rightPressed=false;
```

Then, add this to the `main` method:

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                game.upPressed=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                game.downPressed=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                game.leftPressed=false;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                game.rightPressed=false;
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                game.upPressed=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                game.downPressed=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                game.leftPressed=true;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                game.rightPressed=true;
                break;

        }
    }
});
```

Basically, you are setting the variables we created to true when the buttons are pressed down and false when they are released. Finally, add a `Timer` in the `main` method:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10,(e)->{
    if (game.upPressed)
    {
        game.moveBallUP();
        game.repaint();
    }

    if (game.downPressed)
    {
        game.moveBallDOWN();
        game.repaint();
    }

    if (game.leftPressed)
    {
        game.moveBallLEFT();
        game.repaint();
    }

    if (game.rightPressed)
    {
        game.moveBallRIGHT();
        game.repaint();
    }
});
timer.start();
```

This will fire every 10 milliseconds and call your move methods if the buttons are pressed.

I have tested this and know that it works, however your move methods move the circle in the wrong directions. I assume you can fix that.

**EDIT:** The mistake is in this line:

```
g2d.fillOval(y, x, 50, 50);
```

Change it to:

```
g2d.fillOval(x,y , 50, 50);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thank you this helped a lot.